# Importing a dmp file created by DataPump into Oracle Express 10g

Tags: oracle-xe, datapump

How do i go about importing a .dmp file created by DataPump into Oracle Express 10g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source and More Information](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php)

Place the dump files in C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump

Schema Imports

impdp -user-/-pass- schemas=-schema- directory=-directory- dumpfile=-file.dmp-

i.e:

impdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log

- you may need to remap